# IE 8: remove node keep children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to remove a node from the dom tree using javascript while keeping it's children. I tested the 3 approaches shown below and they work fine in Firefox but do not in IE 8 (see example below).

```
function removeNodeKeepChildren(node){
    // approach 1
    jQuery(node.parentNode).children().map(function (index) {
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).contents());
    });

    // approach 2
    // doesn't work with content() either
    jQuery(node.parentNode).html(jQuery(node).html());

    // approach 3
    var childfragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length;i++){
            childfragment.appendChild((node.childNodes[i]).cloneNode());
    }
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(childfragment,node);
}
```

Example input node:

```
<span class="A1">
    start text
    <span class="F">
        bold text
    </span>
    end text
</span>
```

what it should result in:

```
    start text
    <span class="F">
        bold text
    </span>
    end text
```

What IE 8 does:

```
    start text
    <span class="F">
    </span>
    end text
```

As you can see IE ignores/removes nested children.

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: What's the problem with this approach `http://jsfiddle.net/NKpMC/` . Its working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NKpMC/)

Comment: You are right. I spotted another error in my code which prevented it from working. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be easy to do like this:

```
function removeKeepChildren(node) {
    var $node = $(node);
    $node.contents().each(function() {
        $(this).insertBefore($node);
    });
    $node.remove();
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/SP4fG/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder why the other jQuery-approaches do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), that's what it's intended for.

```
<span class="A1">
    start text
    <span class="F">
        bold text
    </span>
    end text
</span>
<script>
  jQuery(function($){$('.F').unwrap();});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice … it seems like there's always going to be yet another jQuery method I wasn't aware of!

Comment: For this I'd need all the possible classes inside the element to remove, didn't I?

Comment: No, you only need to select 1 childNode of the element you want to remove

Answer (score 3):

Next is most simplest and fastest native javascript code:

```
function removeNodeKeepChildren(node) {
  if (!node.parentElement) return;
  while(node.firstChild)
  {
    node.parentElement.insertBefore(node.firstChild, node);
  }
  node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3J7K/

Comment: "most simplest" … i appreciate nice vanilla JS … how about using spaces, though? I mean, at least in SO posts that helps readability a lot.

Comment: Very nice! Since I am very new to javascript this is very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: This really nice, simplest easiest!

Answer (score 2):

@Jon's approach, sans iteration:

```
function removeKeepChildren(node) {
    var $node = $(node);
    var contents = $node.contents();
    $node.replaceWith(contents);
}
```

**[See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/SP4fG/1/)**

---

@Dr.Molle's answer should be the accepted one.