# Remove span - tags and keep the content in an <td> parent tag

Tags: javascript, tags

i have for example this:

```
<td "class=name">
    <span class="removed">one</span>
    <span class="added">two</span>
</td>
```

or this:

```
<td class=name> one
    <span class="removed">two</span>
    <span class="added">three</span>
</td>
```

or this:

```
<div>
    one
    <span class="added">two</span>
    three four 
    <span class="removed">five</span>
    six
</div>
```

and want to change it with JavaScript (without JQuery) to this:

```
<td "class=name">
    two
</td>
```

or this:

```
<td class=name> 
    one
    three
</td>
```

or this:

```
<div>
    one
    two
    three
    four
    six
</div>
```

can't figure it out. and only found a lot of jquery stuff like replaceWith and so on, but need pure javascript for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12562101/459897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the span tags you have that you want removing have a class of removed or added and testing them using the class doesn't affect any of your other html you could try this.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i=0; i<spans.length;i++)
{
  if(spans[i].className == "added")
  {
     var container = spans[i].parentNode;
     var text = spans[i].innerHTML;
     container.innerHTML += text;
     container.removeChild(spans[i]);
  }
  else if(spans[i].className == "removed")
  {
      var container = spans[i].parentNode;
      container.removeChild(spans[i]);
  }
}
```

Otherwise you need to find a way by ID or class name perhaps to grab the container of the span tags and do something similar. For instance like this

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var spans = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("span");   

for(var i=0; i<spans.length;i++)
{
  if(spans[i].className == "added")
  {
     var text = spans[i].innerHTML;
  }
  myDiv.innerHTML += text;
  myDiv.removeChild(spans[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

Try [here](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) for an idea of how to implement this code using a `getElementsByClassName()` function which might simplify this. It returns an array like `getElementsByTagName()` does which you can iterate over.

Comment: thank you for that. so that is the way how i can remove the tags. but if class="added", i need the content of the span text exactly at this position. (like in the example with the div tags)

Comment: @MartinWaldherr Please see my amended answer. Simply test for the class added and then grab the innerHTML of the span tag and add it to your parent container, i.e the DIV or the TD element.

Comment: use jQuery... or any other framework that takes care of the cross-browser stuff for you. Don't reinvent the wheel. Using getElementsByTagName just to circumvent IE's lack of class support is a bad approach. The least you can do is write getbyclassname for yourself, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7410949/851604

Comment: basically works fine. but there is still a problem and i think thats the main difficulty. cause of the += the text of the added tag is appended. but i need it at the position of the text where the span tag was. for example:
one two three <span class="added">four</span> five six
the solution gives:
one two three five six four
i need:
one two three four five six

Comment: so that is the way how i finally did it.
got my span element with class added with a querySelector
var added = this.node.querySelector('.added');
if (added) {
var added_text = added.innerHTML;
var parent = added.parentNode;
parent.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(added_text), added);}

same with removed but only with parent.removeChild

Answer (score 4):

Here is the best and easiest method that only requires one line of code and uses jQuery:

```js
$('.added').contents().unwrap();
```

Breakdown:

- `$('.added')` = Selects the element with the `added` class.
- `.contents()` = Grabs the text inside the selected element.
- `.unwrap()` = Unwraps the text removing the `<span>` and `</span>` tags while keeping the content in the exact same location.

Answer (score -3):

You can remove any html class with the following code:

```
<div id="target_div">one<span class="added">two</span>three four<span class="removed">five</span>six</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
function remove_html_tag(tag,target_div){
        var content=document.getElementById(target_div).innerHTML;
        var foundat=content.indexOf("<"+tag,foundat);
        while (foundat>-1){
            f2=content.indexOf(">",foundat);
            if (f2>-1) {content=content.substr(0,foundat)+content.substr(f2+1,content.length);}
            f2=content.indexOf("</"+tag+">",foundat);
            if (f2>-1){content=content.substr(0,f2)+content.substr(f2+3+tag.length,content.length);}
            foundat=content.indexOf("<"+tag,foundat);
        }document.getElementById(target_div).innerHTML=content;}
</script>

<a href="javascript:remove_html_tag('span','target_div')">Remove span tag</a>
```